# Improving time complexity in a sorted left-child-right-sibling tree

Tags: c, data-structures, tree

From my understanding, in an already **sorted** left-child-right-sibling tree, if I want to add a child to it let's say "F" after "E" I would have to traverse each of the sibling so that makes its time complexity of O(n). Is this the most optimal? Is there a way to increase efficiency? If so, how?

```
    A
   /
  B->C->D->E
```

Comment: You could replace the sibling list with something else such as a balanced binary tree, but that would make the nodes larger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> if I want to add a child to it let's say "F" after "E" I would have to traverse each of the sibling

For the particular operation you describe, on the particular tree you describe: yes.

> so that makes its time complexity of O(n).

No, it does not.  That analysis makes an inappropriate generalization from a single case.

A left-child-right-sibling tree is normally used as a binary-tree representation of a *k*-ary tree for some *k* greater than 2.  In that case, the performance characteristics are not different from those of the corresponding *k*-ary tree.

A key point that you seem to be overlooking is that in any given left-child-right-sibling tree, the number of siblings of any node will be bounded by a constant.  Therefore, the cost of traversing the siblings of a node does not scale with the total number of nodes.  Instead, it is O(*k*) = O(1).

Consider also what the tree resulting from the insertion might be.  If your example corresponds to a 5-(or more)-ary tree, then it might be

```
    A
   /
  B->C->D->E->F
```

, but if it corresponds to a 4-ary tree then that is not a possibility.  Instead, the result could be any of these:

```
    A
   /
  B->C->D->F 
          /
         E

    A
   /
  C->D->E->F 
 /
B


    A
   /
  B->C->E->F 
       /
      D
```

or many others.  If you build that out further, you will see that as long as the tree is approximately balanced, no, searching the tree for a key or for an insertion position does not cost O(n), but instead O(log n), just like for a straight k-ary (including binary) tree.

> Is this the most optimal? Is there a way to increase efficiency? If so, how?

Insertion strategies that produce more balanced trees will lead to better worst-case search efficiency than those that produce imbalanced trees.  The overall worst possible case is indeed a branchless tree, which is equivalent to a linked list, but nothing in the question is inconsistent with a strategy that yields better search results.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add elements only after the last element `'E'`, then you can make it constant by keeping the pointer to the element `E` stored in `A` and after adding `F` update the pointer that is store in `A`.

If you want to add any element and want to still keep the elements sorted, then you can create a `Binary Tree`, and have achieve `O(log2 N)` time-complexity. You can improve further that data structure by making that a balanced tree (*i.e.,* [AVL Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree)). `AVLs` have a better average, and worst-case, complexity than binary trees, because they avoid that certain sub-trees can get too long, or even in the extreme cases, having a list as a child.